# Is there some kind of "patterns" when coding bash scripts?

Tags: bash, documentation

In Java, we have Javadoc and some different styles when programming. In Python, there's pep8.

I'm creating some bash scripts for my own use, and would like to know from you, experienced bash users, if there's some kind of "pattern" like indentation, documentation for functions, etc. A book or a website with some references.

Comment: While it's not a standard by any means, I wrote a short article on [template method pattern in BASH](http://quickshiftin.com/blog/2014/01/template-method-pattern-bash/). There are also some BASH frameworks out there you might like or take inspiration from, just google for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excellent answer to this question can be found here: [design patterns or best practices for shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78497/design-patterns-or-best-practices-for-shell-scripts)

Comment: well excellent for us but not for the moderator that closed it as "not constructive"..